# What is the link between <YOUR-FIREBASE>.firebaseio.com and home.nest.com

Tags: python, firebase, nest-api

I can talk to firebaseio using [python-firebase](https://ozgur.github.io/python-firebase/) but I am not finding any tutorials on how to actually communicate with a NEST device using firebaseio.

None of the examples on firebaseio have anything to do with NEST and likewise it seems none of the NEST examples have anything to do with firebaseio.

Is the firebaseio account supposed to somehow import the data from home.nest.com? How do I link the two?

---

Why would I want to authenticate with firebaseio unless it has the NEST's data?

[python-firebase](https://ozgur.github.io/python-firebase/):

> **Authentication**
>
> Authentication in Firebase is nothing but to simply creating a token
>   that conforms to the JWT standarts and, putting it into the
>   querystring with the name auth. The library creates that token for you
>   so you never end up struggling with constructing a valid token on your
>   own. If the data has been protected against write/read operations with
>   some security rules, the backend sends an appropriate error message
>   back to the client with the status code 403 Forbidden.

```
from firebase import firebase
firebase = firebase.FirebaseApplication('https://your_storage.firebaseio.com', authentication=None)
result = firebase.get('/users', None, {'print': 'pretty'})
print result
{'error': 'Permission denied.'}

authentication = firebase.Authentication('THIS_IS_MY_SECRET', 'ozgurvt@gmail.com', extra={'id': 123})
firebase.authentication = authentication
print authentication.extra
{'admin': False, 'debug': False, 'email': 'ozgurvt@gmail.com', 'id': 123, 'provider': 'password'}

user = authentication.get_user()
print user.firebase_auth_token
"eyJhbGciOiAiSFMyNTYiLCAidHlwIjogIkpXVCJ9.eyJhZG1pbiI6IGZhbHNlLCAiZGVidWciOiBmYWxzZSwgIml
hdCI6IDEzNjE5NTAxNzQsICJkIjogeyJkZWJ1ZyI6IGZhbHNlLCAiYWRtaW4iOiBmYWxzZSwgInByb3ZpZGVyIjog
InBhc3N3b3JkIiwgImlkIjogNSwgImVtYWlsIjogIm96Z3VydnRAZ21haWwuY29tIn0sICJ2IjogMH0.lq4IRVfvE
GQklslOlS4uIBLSSJj88YNrloWXvisRgfQ"

result = firebase.get('/users', None, {'print': 'pretty'})
print result
{'1': 'John Doe', '2': 'Jane Doe'}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Nest operates its own servers that are protocol-compatible with the Firebase hosted service. That said, there are some minor differences. While you can still use the Firebase client libraries (and REST wrappers, like python-firebase), you need to follow specific instructions (Nest Intro [here](https://developer.nest.com/documentation/nest-api-intro)).

The major change has to deal with how you create a new Firebase instance: instead of using `https://<your-firebase>.firebaseio.com`, you use `wss://developer-api.nest.com`. You then use your Nest auth token to authenticate. The Nest-ified JS would look like:

```
var dataRef = new Firebase('wss://developer-api.nest.com');
dataRef.auth(nestToken);
```

The Python should look similar:

```
from firebase import firebase
authentication = firebase.Authentication('YOUR_NEST_TOKEN', 'YOUR_EMAIL', extra={})
firebase = firebase.FirebaseApplication('wss://developer-api.nest.com', authentication)
```

Typically for Nest, you only need the token, rather than the email or the extra, which means you may have to use the other [python-firebase library](https://github.com/mikexstudios/python-firebase), or modify the source to allow a provider other than wrapping Simple Login. Looks like the original library never uses the email field (see [this](https://github.com/ozgur/python-firebase/blob/master/firebase/firebase.py#L172-L195) comment). Another change that would have to be made is to [change the asserts](https://github.com/ozgur/python-firebase/blob/master/firebase/firebase.py#L229) that all Firebase URL's start with `https` and instead allow them to start with `https` or `wss`.

Also, instead of using the regular Firebase tools (Like the Firebase Dashboard at `<your-firebase>.firebaseio.com`, or our Chrome extension [Vulcan](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/vulcan-by-firebase/oippbnlmebalopjbkemajgfbglcjhnbl?hl=en)), you use the [Nest Chrome Extension](https://developer.nest.com/documentation/chrome-extension) to manage your Nest devices.

Hopefully this helps!

Comment: Where does the YOUR_NEST_TOKEN come from? is it the client_id or client_secret?

Comment: I have tried the same thing, but was not able to extract data from firebase object. I already have NEST_TOKEN. How should I get data from this firebase object?

Answer (score 2):

The base URI for the Nest Firebase instance is https://developer-api.nest.com and Nest uses their own [OAuth authentication](https://developer.nest.com/documentation/how-to-auth) to allow a developer access to the user's data.

Not familiar with python-firebase, but it looks like you can change the Firebase instance URI to point at Nest and pass in an external OAuth token (both supported by Firebase written clients as well)