# Unable to fetch data from nest using python-firebase

Tags: python, firebase, nest-api

I tried to get data from [nest](https://developers.nest.com/) using python-firebase module but I unable to fetch. I follow the answer given in post [What is the link between <YOUR-FIREBASE>.firebaseio.com and home.nest.com](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25872562/what-is-the-link-between-your-firebase-firebaseio-com-and-home-nest-com) I have valid nest token.

Comment: Hi @Vinay-kashyap, what did you do in term of steps to try to get the resolution?

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure exactly what you are trying to do but you might consider looking at the REST API instead of python-firebase.  Here is a code sample using the requests library and ujson to read device data.

```
import requests
import ujson

s = requests.session()

auth_url = "https://api.home.nest.com/oauth2/access_token"

auth_body = {
    "code": "AUTHORIZATION_CODE",
    "client_id": "CLIENT_ID",
    "client_secret": "CLIENT_SECRET",
    "grant_type": "authorization_code"
    }

auth_r = s.post(url=auth_url, data=auth_body)
auth_content = ujson.loads(auth_r.content)

auth_content['access_token']

devices_url = "https://developer-api.nest.com/devices?auth=" + auth_content['access_token']

devices_r = s.get(devices_url)

devices_r.json()
```

Comment: The key here is there is no link between *.firebaseio.com and Nest's API service. Nest is hosting their own instance of Firebase at developer-api.nest.com